# Patten matching to check for non-empty argument list

Tags: beginner, validation, elixir

I'm learning Elixir.
while building a trivial cli application (as seen here http://asquera.de/blog/2015-04-10/writing-a-commandline-app-in-elixir/) I'm defining a module that implements a `main/1` function that accepts a `List` as an argument.

My question is: What is the best way to pattern match a method against a non-empty list ?

This is what i did and it seems to work but i was wondering if the elixir community has better suggestions ( maybe `def main(args) when is_list(args) and length(args) > 0 do` is considered *better* ? )

```
defmodule Cli do
    def main([]) do
        IO.puts "arguments are needed"
    end

    def main([_|_] = args) do
        options = parse_args(args)
        input = options[:name]
        size = options[:size]
        output(input, size)
    end

    def parse_args(args) do
        {options, _, _} = OptionParser.parse args,
            switches: [name: :string, size: :integer]
        options
    end

    def output() do
        IO.puts "Missing required --name parameter"
    end

    def output(input) do
        # defaulting size to 50
        output(input, 50)
    end

    def output(input, block_size) do
        IO.puts "you entered #{input} and #{block_size}"
    end
end
```

Comment: <joke>I find this piece of code offensive: `def main([_|_] = args) do`</joke>

Comment: The question looks a bit sketchy. What arguments do you expect, and what do they mean?

Comment: args should be a list of command line arguments (es if you call `cmd --foo bar`, args will be `["foo", "bar"]` if you call `cmd` args will be `[]`)

Comment: @Dex'ter my question is: how would you rewrite that?

Comment: As stands, if this question were open, I think it would be closed as stub code from `      # do stuff with args`.  There may not be much happening in your trivial application, but there is more than you show here.

Comment: I extended the example: I don't even get why my question is a bad question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've implemented it by pattern matching against empty lists with `def main([])`. If an empty list is passed to `main`, it will be caught here. In the second `def main(args)`, `args` should never be an empty list.

If you want to make sure that `args` is a list, you could use a guard clause: `def main(args) when is_list(args)`. (You should then write a catch-all third definition: `def main(_)`).